# "I became good friend with the man I met yesterday." or "I became good friendS with the man I met yesterday."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrases, singular-vs-plural

> I became good friend with the man I met yesterday.

> I became good friend{s} with the man I met yesterday.

Should "friend" be in plural or singular? Which one is right: "friend" or "friends"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can be "friends with" someone, or "a friend of" someone. You can not be "friend with" someone.

Answer (score 2):

> I became good friend with the man I met yesterday.

This is incorrect as you are are speaking about you and the man. Hence the plural, friends, is correct.